# Crashes When i input a string

Tags: c

The program crashes whenever I try to add or register a new political party, like adding a new string to the ragged array `char**Political_PartiesDB`. I'm just trying to write a voting system software that will enable a user to add political parties of their choice but the array cannot hold a single string. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void PassCodeDisplay(void);
void WelcomeDisplay(void);
void DateTimeDisplay(void);
int AdminDisplay(void);
void DisplayRegisteredParties(char *Ragged_Array[], int Array_Size);
void VoterMenuDisplay(void);
void Wrt_Voters(void);
double Result_Percent(int);

typedef enum
{
    Register_PP = 1,
    Exit_Program
} AdminMenu;
AdminMenu Administrator_Menu;

typedef enum
{
    start_voting = 1,
    Exit_program
} SubMenu;
SubMenu Sub_Menu;

typedef enum
{
    Next_Voter = 1,
    Current_Statistics,
    End_Voting_Process
} VotMenu;
VotMenu Voter_Menu;

int selection, registered, PassCode;
/*
 * 
 */
void PassCodeDisplay(void)
{
    int PassCode_cnt = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Administrative PassCode\n");
        printf(" >>"), scanf("%d", &PassCode);
        PassCode_cnt++;        /*Counts the amount of error in PassCode trials*/
        if (PassCode_cnt == 3) /*terminates your program whenever you input three wrong PassCodes*/
        {
            printf(" You Have incorrectly typed your PassCode %d times, Terminating program...\n", PassCode_cnt);
            exit(0);
        }
    } while (PassCode != 9920);
}

void WelcomeDisplay(void)
{

    printf("\t|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n");
    printf("\t||INDEPENDENT ELECTORAL COMISSION||\n");
    printf("\t|||||||MOBILE VOTING SYSTEM||||||||\n");
    printf("\t|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n");
    putchar('\n');
    printf(" Welcome Administrator,\n ");
}

void DateTimeDisplay(void)
{
    printf("%s\n%s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
}

int AdminDisplay(void)
{
    selection = 0;
    printf("ADMINISTRATOR:\n ");
    printf("1. Register Political Parties.\n");
    printf(" 2. Exit Program.\n");
    printf(" >>");
    scanf("%d", &selection);
    return selection;
}

int SubDisplay(void)
{
    printf("ADMINISTRATOR SUBMENU:\n ");
    printf("1. Start Voting.\n");
    printf(" 2. Exit Program.\n");
    printf(" >>");
    scanf("%d", &selection);
    return selection;
}

void DisplayRegisteredParties(char *Politcal_PartiesDB[], int NPolitical_Parties)
{
    for (registered = 1; registered <= NPolitical_Parties; registered++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n", registered, Politcal_PartiesDB[registered]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int NPolitical_Parties = 0;
    char **Political_PartiesDB;

    DateTimeDisplay();
    WelcomeDisplay();
    PassCodeDisplay();

    if (PassCode == 9920)
    {
        DateTimeDisplay();
        WelcomeDisplay();
        switch (AdminDisplay())
        {

        case Register_PP:
            printf("How many political parties do you want to register?\n >>");
            scanf("%d", &NPolitical_Parties);
            *Political_PartiesDB[NPolitical_Parties];
            printf("Enter Names Of Political Parties.\n");
            for (registered = 1; registered <= NPolitical_Parties; registered++)
            {
                printf("Political Party %d of %d\n >>", registered, NPolitical_Parties);
                Political_PartiesDB[NPolitical_Parties] = (char *)calloc(10, sizeof(char));
                assert(Political_PartiesDB[NPolitical_Parties] != NULL);
                scanf("%s", Political_PartiesDB[registered]);
            }

            switch (SubDisplay())
            {
            case start_voting:

                printf("Registered Parties:\n");
                DisplayRegisteredParties(Political_PartiesDB, NPolitical_Parties);

            case Exit_program:
                exit(0);
            default:
                printf("\nERROR: Wrong Selection!\n");
                exit(0);
            }

        case Exit_Program:
            exit(0);

        default:
            printf("\nERROR: Wrong Selection!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("PassCode incorrect! Try Again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly, please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
It seems unlikely that all that code and all those functions are necessary to illustrate the problem.  Your problem is probably that you didn't allocate enough of the correct memory.  Your code in `case Register_PP:` in `main()` should be in a function.

Comment: You have: `*Political_PartiesDB[NPolitical_Parties];` — that is a mostly no-op statement that references unallocated memory.  You need to allocate enough space (with `malloc()` et al) for the number of parties you plan to enter.  (No, you can't afford to use a VLA, so putting `char` in front would not work properly.)

Answer (score 0):

You should fix calloc for this.

```
Political_PartiesDB=(char**) calloc(NPolitical_Parties, sizeof(char*));
```

And also you are using calloc in wrong index in this

```
     Political_PartiesDB[NPolitical_Parties] = (char *)calloc(10, sizeof(char));
     assert(Political_PartiesDB[NPolitical_Parties] != NULL);
     scanf("%s", Political_PartiesDB[registered]);
```

But you should change indexes like this

```
    for (registered = 1; registered <= NPolitical_Parties; registered++)
            {
                printf("Political Party %d of %d\n >>", registered, NPolitical_Parties);
                Political_PartiesDB[registered-1] = (char *)calloc(10, sizeof(char));
                assert(Political_PartiesDB[registered-1] != NULL);
                scanf(" %s", Political_PartiesDB[registered-1]);
            }
```

or (even better), indexing from 0 like any normal C program (using a characteristically short index name), and protecting against overflow of the very short party name field:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < NPolitical_Parties; i++)
    {
        printf("Political Party %d of %d\n >>", i, NPolitical_Parties);
        Political_PartiesDB[i] = (char *)calloc(10, sizeof(char));
        assert(Political_PartiesDB[i] != NULL);
        scanf("%9s", Political_PartiesDB[i]);
    }
```